Knit Not Working in Second YAML Header - RStudio
I am trying to use a second YAML header in an R markdown file so that I can dynamically name the output file as well as the output location using a variable initialized later in the program (through inline r code). In this second YAML header I use the knit keyword, with a value that is a function that specifies the file output name and directory using the rmarkdown:render function. This function works as expected when it is in the top/first YAML header, but when I move this function into a second YAML header, it does not work as expected, even if I don't use any inline r code.
This is my first and second YAML header, which I used to test the knit function without any use of variables. It works as expected, and the title call in the second header does pull the variable into the name.
---
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{fvextra} 
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}

knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { 
      user <- Sys.getenv('username');
  
      out_dir <- paste0("../../main_directory");
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding, 
                        output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir, 'A generic name.pdf')) })
output: pdf_document
---

room <- some_code_that_pulls_room

---
title: "`r room`"
---

Now I wanted to use the variable, room, initialized later in the program so that I can dynamically  name the file and output directory. So if the room is 'A', I want to name the output "A.pdf" stored in "../../main_directory/A" folder. If the room is 'B', then "B.pdf" stored in the "../../main_directory/B" folder.
To accomplish this, I edited the first and second YAML header as follows:
---
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{fvextra} 
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}

output: pdf_document
---

room <- some_code_that_pulls_room

---
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { 
      user <- Sys.getenv('username');
      out_dir <- paste0("../../main_directory", `r room`);
      fname <- paste0(`r room`, ".pdf")
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding, 
                        output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir, fname))})

title: "`r room`"
---

Although the title still works as expected, the whole knit function does not work. Can you not have the knit keyword in the second YAML header? Is there any other way to conditionally name the knitted file/directory based on a variable that appears later in the code?
